# Display the selected record

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

I have a page that display of all News in a database, which I get with function

```
IList<News> GetAll();
```

I then bind the list to a repeater to display all the news. If a user clicks on news N, he is redirected to page.aspx?id=N

If the QueryString["id"] is set, then I get one of my News like this:

```
News news = sNewsService.Get(int.Parse(id));
```

Now, I would like to display this single news, but I cannot bind it to a Repeater as it does not implement IListSource or IEnumerable.

Is there any other way to display the properties of one news instead of writing every property value to a different Label like lText = news.Text; lTitle = news.Title;... or wrapping the news in a List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the product to MVC and created custom DTO's/Views

Answer (score 1):

The [DetailsView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx) control is designed to display a single record.  Not sure if that might help.

Comment: The DetailsView control can be bound to a data source that implements the System.Collections.IEnumerable interface, so this will not work by itself.

Comment: You could try to wrap your object in an ObjectDataSource

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a typical Master-Details scenario where your Repeater displays a List of `News` objects and then allows you to redirect to a Details page which will display additional detail about the selected `News` object.

In this case, I would suggest a [FormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.aspx) instead of a DetailsView which will allow you greater control over the details display since it requires user defined templates instead of preconfigured Row based display.

Since your News class does not implement `IEnumerable`, it is necessary that you use an [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx.aspx) to enable databinding. This datasource will be able to wrap your class and allow the FormView to bind to it using [Eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx) based lookup syntax.